# How to install yum on centos

Tags: linux, centos

I removed `/usr/bin/yum` by mistake.

How to re install yum on centos6
Please help me ;(

I followed website explanation
but I got this error `Failed dependencies: blah,blah`
or `yum-2.2.1-1.centos4.noarch.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID ###: NOKEY`

ps. I try this

```
wget http://mirrors.163.com/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/python-iniparse-0.3.1-2.1.el6.noarch.rpm
```

and `rpm -ivH yum-3.2.29-60.el6.centos.noarch.rpm`

then I got this error

```
 Failed dependencies:
    /usr/bin/python is needed by yum-3.2.29-60.el6.centos.noarch
    python >= 2.4 is needed by yum-3.2.29-60.el6.centos.noarch
    python(abi) = 2.6 is needed by yum-3.2.29-60.el6.centos.noarch
    python-sqlite is needed by yum-3.2.29-60.el6.centos.noarch
```

so I copied old version yum
and This error what i got

```
-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python2.6: bad interpreter: no such file or directory
```

(I upgraded python2.6 to python2.7)

Comment: What if you try http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BrokenVserver  4# installing yum?

Comment: If you both removed yum *and* upgraded the system python you have a **very** broken system. You should **never** upgrade the system python on a RedHat/CentOS system. That's what SCLs and alternatively named packages in repos like IUS (if they have them for python) are for.

Comment: What does `rpm -q yum python` say? What does `rpm -Va` say (possibly quite a lot of output for this command)? The first thing you are going to need to do is remove any non-standard python/etc. packages.

Answer (score -2):

Is aptitude or apt-get available on the machine?

```
apt-get install yum
```

Or have a look here:
http://openvz.org/Install_yum

Comment: apt-get is not centOS command and Your link doesn't work. anyway thank you :)

Comment: Which way did you try? Via apt-get or via the openvpn.org website?

Comment: both of your solutions.

Comment: Do you have a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system?